# Resistance calculation

Tags: resistors, resistance

[image: Schematic]

Are these resistors in parallel? A question is asked to find the equivalent resistance between X1 and X2; to my knowledge, these resistors are like parallel connections. But the choices are given as:

- A. 2 Ohms
- B. 4 Ohms
- C. 8 Ohms
- D. 12 Ohms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is these resistors are in parallel ?

Hmm ...

[image]

Comment: I see what you're doing visually, but I think this answer could be improved with a little bit of text. :)

Comment: It's like a peek into the workings of an EE's mind. Very good.

Answer (score 3):

Redraw the circuit so that it makes more sense is the main clue or even colour code all the nodes: -

[image]

Count the nodes. How many are there? Does this tell you how the resistors are connected? It should.

Answer (score -1):

The right answer is 2 ohms. The equation can be found 
at [parallel resistors](http://www.1728.org/resistrs.htm)

An instructor put this on test when I was a student, but not multiple choice, just pen and paper and slide rule. This was before calculators were invented.

Comment: A good answer would address the schematic and explain how to redraw it or re-imagine it so that it's obvious how components are connected. Providing the eventual final answer with a link to parallel calculations, I don't think is as helpful. Finally, the anecdotal portion about your past is completely superfluous.