# how to calculate time for timer relay

Tags: resistance, timer, 555

In the below circuit of Timer Relay, how I can calculate the time for C1 to be fully charged?
please don't use regulator, transistor or any other device I just want to use Resistance and want to calculate how much resistance required to charge the C1 for how much time?
If ohms law(E=IR) is suitable than what is the relation of (I) with C1?

[image]

Comment: It's easy to show that the time to charge to the 2/3 supply transition is t= \$R C \$ln\$(3)\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitor resistor charge time: -

[image]

If the applied voltage is 12V the capacitor charges to 63.2% of 12V in a time equal to capacitance in farads x resistance in ohms. In twice this time it gets another 63.2% closer to 12V i.e. 86.5%. Each duration of time equal to CR it gets another 63.2% closer. See below: -

[image]

> how I can calculate the time for C1 to be fully charged?

Theoretically a capacitor never gets to 12V but, for practical purposes it gets to over 99% charge after 5 x CR.

As for the circuit in the question, it appears to be using a 555 timer chip and the relevant point at which this activates the chip is not to be confused with "fully charged". Read the data on the 555 to determine what that point in time is.

Comment: You mean if I have 12 V battery and 10 ohms resistance and 20F capacitor than the capacitor will take 1000 seconds for being charge upto 99%?

Comment: What if i change the applied voltage from 12 volts to any other value? any example?

Comment: @Andriopak Voltage doesn't come into it and yes for CR = 200, the cap will charge to over 99% of the supplied voltage in 1000 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you've shown is that of a 555 timer wired as a monostable multivibrator and if S1 is pressed and released, pin 3 will go high as soon as S1 is made and will turn the relay ON for:

$$  \text {T} = 1.1 \times{R1}\times{C1}\ \text {seconds.}$$

However, if S1 is pressed for longer than T, and then released, U1 won't time out at all; it'll just follow S1.

So, assuming that S1 will be released before U1 times out, and that your criterion for "fully charged" is specific to your question and is how long it takes to charge up C1 through R1 until it gets to the voltage required to de-energize the relay, you have your answer.

On a more general note, if you have a circuit like this:

[image]

then the time for Vt to rise to any voltage between GND (0V) and V when S1 is made, and held made, can be determined by:

$$ \text{T} = kRC \ \text{seconds,} $$

where

$$ k = l_{n}\  \frac{V}{V - Vt} $$

and \$ l_{n}\$ is the natural logarithm.

For example, let's say we have a circuit where V is 10 volts, C is 1 microfarad, and we want to find the resistance which will cause Vt to rise from zero volts to one volt in one second.

In that case we first solve for k:

$$ k = l_{n}\  \frac{V}{V - Vt} = l_{n}\  \frac{10V}{9V} = 0.105 $$

Then, since

$$ \text{T} = kRC \ \text{seconds,} $$

we can rearrange and solve for R like this:

$$ \text{R} = \frac{T}{kC} = \frac{1s}{0.105 \times 1\cdot10^{-6}\mu F} =\ 952k\Omega $$

Answer (score 0):

When wired in a monostable configuration, as in the question, the output of the 555 goes high when the trigger input goes low (more precisely, below 1/3 of the supply voltage); and *T* seconds later, when the threshold voltage reaches 2/3 of the supply voltage the output goes back to zero.  But why 1/3 V and 2/3 V? Because of the way the 555 in constructed.  (We'll deal with the time delay *T* later.)

Here is a block diagram of the 555 configured as a monostable:

[image]

Note the three resistors to the left of the two comparators.  Each of them are 5K, and the three in series form a voltage divider divide the supply voltage in thirds, so a voltage of 2/3V goes to the - terminal of the top comparator, and 1/3V goes to the + terminal of the bottom comparator.

*A little trivia: the name of the chip -- 555 -- comes from these three 5K resistors*.

The threshold input level is normally high (greater than 2/3 V) for a 555 in this configuration so the top comparator is on because the voltage on the + input (threshold) is greater then the voltage on the - input (2/3 V), keeping the RS flip-flop reset.  Transistor T1 is turned on, keeping the capacitor C discharged.

Note the in this monostable configuration, the trigger input and threshold input are tied together.

When the trigger goes low (below 1/3 V), the top comparator will turn off, and the bottom comparator will turn on since the voltage on the + terminal (1/3 V) is more then the voltage on the trigger input, and the flip-flop will be set.  This will cause the output to go high.

T1 is now turned off, so capacitor C begins to charge up through resistor R.  Once the threshold voltage reaches 2/3 V, the top comparator is turned on, causing the flip-flop to reset again, the output to go to zero, and the capacitor to discharge since T1 is turned back on.

[image]

What about the voltage levels across the middle resistor, from 1/3V to 2/3V?  If the inputs on the trigger/threshold pins fall in-between the two voltages, nothing happens.  This provides hysteresis so the flip-flop doesn't change rapidly when the inputs are near their thresholds.  In fact, sometimes the 555 is employed as a Schmitt trigger just because of the way it is constructed.

The time constant that governs how long the delay (i.e how long it takes the capacitor to charge up to 2/3 V, is

$$T=1.1\space RC \space\space seconds$$

This very similar to the standard equation for an typical RC delay, but there is an extra factor of 1.1 in the equation.  Where did the 1.1 come from?

The current through RC connected in series is:

$$i = ( \frac{V}{R} ) \space e^{-(\frac{T}{RC})}$$

The voltage change of the both edges of resistor (R) is demanded by the following formula.

$$iR = V e^{-(\frac{T}{RC})}$$

The time when the voltage of the both edges of capacitor (C) becomes 2/3 of power supply voltage (V) is time out period. That is, it is when the voltage across resistor becomes 1/3 of power supply voltage, since the resistor and capacitor are connected in series between Vcc and ground.

Replacing \$iR\$ by \$V\$, and dividing by 3 because want 1/3 of the voltage, we have:

$$\frac{V}{3} = V e^{-(\frac{T}{RC})}$$

Dividing both sides by \$V\$, then taking the natural logarithm and rearranging a little, we have::

$$T = -RC\space ln (\frac{1}{3})$$

so: $$T = 1.1\space RC$$

Actually my calculator gives -1.09861 for \$ln (\frac{1}{3})\$ but -1.1 is close enough.